# C4 capture camera image example

Tags: ios, camera, c4

Hei,

just starting to get into C4 and so far my experience has been great.
I'm replicating the taking a photo with the camera-example at the moment and for some reason when I do everything as described in the tutorial (http://www.c4ios.com/tutorials/takingSnapshots) I get the following mistake:
"No visible @interface for 'TakePhoto' declares the selector 'listenFor:from Object:'" (Take Photo is the file I'm working in)
I think I have to declare "imageWasCaptured" in the class definition but I don't know as what? 
Any suggestions?

updated: here is the code
https://github.com/susemiessner/Urban-Alphabets/tree/master/urbanAlphabets
or just plain copied
**TakePhoto.h**

```
#import "C4CanvasController.h"

@interface TakePhoto : C4CanvasController

@end
```

**TakePhoto.m**

```
    #import "TakePhoto.h"
    #define NavBarHeight 42
    #define TopBarFromTop 20

    @interface TakePhoto ()

    @end

    @implementation TakePhoto {
        //common variables
        UIColor *navBarColor;
        UIColor *buttonColor;
        UIColor *typeColor;

        //top toolbar
        C4Shape *topNavBar;
        C4Font *fatFont;
        C4Label *takePhoto;



        //camera
        C4Camera *cam;

        //bottom Toolbar
        C4Shape *bottomNavBar;
        C4Button *takePhotoButton;
    }
    -(void) setup{
        navBarColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.96875 green:0.96875 blue:0.96875 alpha:1];
        buttonColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8984275 green:0.8984275 blue:0.8984275 alpha:1];
        typeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.19921875 green:0.19921875 blue:0.19921875 alpha:1];

        [self topBarSetup];
        [self bottomBarSetup];
        [self cameraSetup];

    }
    -(void)topBarSetup{
        topNavBar=[C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(0, TopBarFromTop, self.canvas.width, NavBarHeight)];
        topNavBar.fillColor=navBarColor;
        topNavBar.lineWidth=0;
        [self.canvas addShape:topNavBar];


        fatFont=[C4Font fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17];
        takePhoto = [C4Label labelWithText:@"Take Photo" font:fatFont];
        takePhoto.center=topNavBar.center;
        [self.canvas addLabel:takePhoto];}

    -(void)cameraSetup{
        cam = [C4Camera cameraWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,TopBarFromTop+NavBarHeight, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height-(2*NavBarHeight+TopBarFromTop))];
        [self.canvas addCamera:cam];
        [cam initCapture];
        //tapping to take image
        [self addGesture:TAP name:@"capture" action:@"capturedImage"];
        [self numberOfTouchesRequired:1 forGesture:@"capture"];
//the following line is where I get the error
        [self listenFor:@"imageWasCaptured" fromObject:@"putCapturedImageOnCanvas"];
    }
    -(void) bottomBarSetup{
        bottomNavBar=[C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(0, self.canvas.height-(NavBarHeight), self.canvas.width, NavBarHeight)];
        bottomNavBar.fillColor= navBarColor;
        bottomNavBar.lineWidth=0;
        [self.canvas addShape:bottomNavBar];

        takePhotoButton=[UIButton buttonWithType: ROUNDEDRECT];
        [takePhotoButton setTitle:@"TakePhoto" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        takePhotoButton.frame=CGRectMake(self.canvas.width/2-50, self.canvas.height-(NavBarHeight), 100, NavBarHeight);
        takePhotoButton.backgroundColor=buttonColor;
        takePhotoButton.tintColor=typeColor;
        [self.canvas addSubview:takePhotoButton];

    }

    -(void) takingPhoto{
        [cam captureImage];
    }
    -(void) captureImage{
        [cam captureImage];
    }
    -(void)putCapturedImageOnCanvas{
        C4Image *img = cam.capturedImage;
        img.width=240;
        img.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.width*2/3, self.canvas.center.y);

    }


    @end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have to add a method to the header file of the class. Can you please post the code for your TakePhoto class (.h and .m) so we can have a look at it.

Comment: the code is now above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your concept working there are a couple of holes in your approach that will prevent you from seeing anything actually happen. Your question is definitely one of them.

To answer your question:

`listenFor:fromObject:` is unrecognized because it actually doesn't exist.

The intention of `listenFor` methods is so that your app, or a specific object, can react to a notification or an action happening somewhere else in the application. **So** what you want to do is run a method when something happens.

Your method should be:

```
[self listenFor:@"imageWasCaptured" fromObject:cam andRunMethod:@"methodName"];
```

You want to listen for when the *camera* has finished capturing and then do something with that...

---

Other things I noticed...

If you want to use a `C4Button`, then the following:

```
takePhotoButton=[UIButton buttonWithType: ROUNDEDRECT];
[takePhotoButton setTitle:@"TakePhoto" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Should be:

```
takePhotoButton = [C4Button buttonWithType:ROUNDEDRECT];
[takePhotoButton setTitle:@"TakePhoto" forState:NORMAL];
```

Also, you're subclassing `C4CanvasController`. To get your `TakePhoto` object's view onto the main canvas you need to create it properly.

To do this in the main canvas I wrote the following in my workspace:

```
#import "C4Workspace.h"
#import "TakePhoto.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace {
    TakePhoto *tp;
}

-(void)setup {
    tp = [TakePhoto new];
    tp.canvas.frame = CGRectMake(30,
                                 30,
                                 self.canvas.width - 60,
                                 self.canvas.height - 60);
    tp.canvas.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10,10);
    tp.canvas.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    tp.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [tp setup];
    tp.mainCanvas = self.canvas;
    [self.canvas addSubview:tp.canvas];
}
@end
```

And, finally, to get your camera's image onto the main canvas, I had do bridge a little. I created a property in `TakePhoto` that lets me set the main canvas in your new controller. You'll notice in the code above the line that states `tp.mainCanvas = self.canvas`...

The `TakePhoto` header now looks like:

```
#import "C4CanvasController.h"

@interface TakePhoto : C4CanvasController
@property (readwrite, strong) C4Window *mainCanvas;
@end
```

And the `putImageOnCanvas` method now looks like:

```
-(void)putCapturedImageOnCanvas{
    C4Image *img = cam.capturedImage;
    img.width=240;
//    img.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.width*2/3, self.canvas.center.y);
    img.center = CGPointMake([C4Math randomInt:self.mainCanvas.width], [C4Math randomInt:self.mainCanvas.height]);
    [self.mainCanvas addImage:img];
    [self.mainCanvas bringSubviewToFront:self.canvas];
}
```

The last two lines put the image on the canvas and then make sure that the `TakePhoto` canvas (i.e. the one with the camera) is brought to the foreground so the newly added image doesn't occlude it.

Because you're using a subclass of a `C4CanvasController` your app structure looks like:

`C4WorkSpace.canvas > TakePhoto.canvas > Camera`

Comment: sorry but I'm still confused here now.
I tried to just run the camera example seperately without anything else. The code is on GitHub https://github.com/susemiessner/Urban-Alphabets/tree/master/cameraTest
it still gives me an uncaught error. 
From what I understand in this `[self listenFor:@"imageWasCaptured" fromObject:cam andRunMethod:@"methodName"];` some other function/method has to return `imageWasCaptured`, or? (Sorry for being so not understanding!!!)

Comment: also I don't really get why you are suggesting adding the subviews differently from the tutorial on subviews. Could you explain that maybe?

Comment: **re: error** I will have a look at your project as soon as I can. There may be a couple of different reasons. First, you can't run camera apps on anything other than a device (i.e. iPhone or iPod) because the simulator can't simulate the camera. If you're using a device then there's something else going on. Right now I don't have a device at home but can check on monday for sure.

Comment: **re: imageWasCaptured** Yes, I can understand why this may be confusing. In a nutshell, the canvas to which you add a camera will run its own `imageWasCaptured` method. There is actually a semi-complicated setup that happens in the `addCamera:` method. Have a look at **line 50** in `C4CanvasController.m`... The confusion might come from 2 places. 1) `imageWasCaptured` is BOTH a method AND a NOTIFICATION 2) This is an API/Language issue that is probably the cause of your confusion (I will have a look at it)

Comment: **re: subviews** I am suggesting a different way of working with subviews because you've chosen to create the `TakePhoto` class as a subclass of `C4CanvasController`... But the controller (i.e. the `TakePhoto` object) is *not* a view, instead it *controls* a subview. So, there's an extra object in the mix. The camera object itself is a view and is added to the canvas of the `TakePhoto` controller. That's why you get `canvas > canvas > camera`...

Comment: p.s. these are all great questions.

Comment: thanks! that all makes sense. 
**re:error** yes, I am running it on a device. It's an iPhone 5 (running iOS7) and I'm building my projects in XCode 5. 
I can maybe try testing it on a 4th Generation iPodTouch tomorrow and see if that helps....
**re subviews and imageWasCaptured** thanks for the explanation! that totally does make sense to me! I'm just in the beginning of a bigger project and can also still change how to handle the different views, so if you suggest one way as better than the other let me know!

Comment: Using a 4 / iPod touch shouldn't make a difference. I'll have a look in the morning.

Comment: Had a look at the "error", and have found that you were using an extra **`:`** in your `[self addGesture:TAP name:@"capture" action:@"captureImage:"];` it should be `@"captureImage"` and not `@"captureImage:"` because the method you declared in your `TakePhoto.h` **doesn't** take a variable.

Comment: amazing! no more app crashing! BIG THANKS!

Comment: No prob. I'm happy you're using C4, so anything I can do to help please ask away! P.S. please feel free to accept the answer.